# resamplig pandas (not as a timeseries)

Tags: resampling, linear-interpolation

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

`index     x     y
0.010     1     Nan
0.011     Nan   3
0.014     NaN   4
0.019     9     Nan
0.020     10    7`

This matrix comes from a concatenation of 2 matrices
I would like to resample the index at equally spaced intervals, say 0.010, 0.012,0.014..... 0.020, filling the NaN with linear interpolation.
Similar to what resample does if index were a time series...

Can anyone send me hints?
I am having an headache with this
Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

```
df1 = A.reindex(A.index.union(np.linspace(0.0,0.1,11)))
df1.interpolate('index').loc[np.linspace(0.0,1.1,11)]
```

This does the trick marvelously.

With the union, I add the indexes that I want that do not appear in the original dataframe.

Then I interpolate and use `loc` to filter only the indexes that I want.